# How to return more than one type in C++ template meta-programming?

Tags: c++, types, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have a simple template metaprogramm that converts many `std::ratio`s into the lowest possible number of `ratio`s. It must return 1 `ratio` if there is no overflow (and it does so) and 2 or more, when there is overflow. Is it possible to achive?

```
template<class R, class ...Rs> struct unite_ratio;

template<intmax_t Num, intmax_t Den> 
struct unite_ratio<std::ratio<Num, Den>>
{
    using type = std::ratio<Num, Den>;
};

template<
    intmax_t Num1, intmax_t Den1, 
    intmax_t Num2, intmax_t Den2,
    class ...Rs
> struct unite_ratio<std::ratio<Num1, Den1>, std::ratio<Num2, Den2>, Rs...>
{
    // here might be an overflow
    static constexpr intmax_t num = 
        std::__static_sign<Den1>::value * std::__static_sign<Den2>::value *
        (Num1 / std::__static_gcd<Num1, Den2>::value) * 
        (Num2 / std::__static_gcd<Num2, Den1>::value);

    // Here might be an overflow as well
    static constexpr intmax_t den =
        (std::__static_abs<Den1>::value / std::__static_gcd<Num2, Den1>::value) *
        (std::__static_abs<Den2>::value / std::__static_gcd<Num1, Den2>::value);

    // returns only one type
    using type = unite_ratio<std::ratio<num, den>, Rs...>;
};
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::vector`.

Comment: std::vector of types?

Comment: Of whatever you want, but sure, that type.

Comment: Does this mean "unite" as in combine or "unit"?

Comment: And how will i use those types later? I need them to instanciate a class that accepts varadic template

Comment: "unite" as in combine

Comment: You can put whatever you want in a `std::vector` so long as you can define what "whatever" is. A template class can define its return value as `std::vector<X>` where `X` can be quite a verbose definition.

Comment: Will it be `constexpr`?

Comment: I normally see tuples used to express a group of types.

Comment: There's nothing special about `std::vector` so presumably it could be. I don't see why not.

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought of that first, but this needs 1..N values, which makes tuple impractical.

Comment: @tadman I don't quite imagine how can I use `vector` in this situation, could you give an answer, please?

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand your question, but admittedly there is a lot going on here and not a lot of clarity on how you intend to use this. Can you give a more concrete example of what you're looking for in terms of results and how those results are used?

Comment: I'm working on extending size of `ratio`. It takes `intmax_t` as template parameters, hence only allow ratio of ~10^20. So i create a `wratio` class that has any number of `std::ratio` parameters. But I want to have the lowest number of them.

Comment: If the result is all of the same (template) type then `std::vector<unite_ratio<...>>` should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that they aren't same templates. I want to store types (not values) and they must be available at compiler time and act like an varadic template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to return more than one type in C++ template meta-programming?

With a type list. It is simply a template class whose variadic list of template arguments are the list of types:

```
template<class...T>
struct types{};
```